# Differentiating the UUID Device to Device

Tags: android, bluetooth, uuid

I have read the bluetooth android developers but I'm unable to clarify one doubt that whether the UUIDs do differ with each application or differ from device to device?

Can any one please tell that one clearly.
Your help is much appreciated.
Thanks :-)

Comment: UUID means "Universal Unique Identifier" so obviously it differ for every device.

Comment: @Haresh - actually, it depends on *which* UUID.  A *service* or *characteristic* UUID for example would be the same on every device which supported that, while a *device* UUID would be different.